# Fields of an Exception object when printed out

Tags: php

Please take a look at the output I get when I print out the contents of an Exception object (using the built-in class here):

```
    Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => My custom message
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 2281488
    [file:protected] => /home/user/scripts/test.php
    [line:protected] => 18
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
)
```

Most of the fields have the `field_name:visibility_keyword` format, but two of them have Exception appear in between. What does this denote?

Also, two other fields, namely `$string` and `$trace`, aren't mentioned in the official manual but I know the latter receives a value when an exception object is thrown within a function, so it contains the order in which functions are called until one of them creates said exception.

The string field gets assigned a value when I try to echo an exception and remains empty unless I echo it before the contents of the object are printed out. Can you please enlighten me on how this field works exactly?

I'd appreciate any input I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with exceptions, it's just how `var_dump()` and `print_r()` display private and protected properties of objects.

Private properties are always shown with the name of the class before `:private`
That tells you which class in the inheritance hierarchy is allowed to access that property.

This isn't needed for protected properties, because any class in the hierarchy can access them.

```
class Class1 {
    private $private1;
    protected $protected1;
    public $public1;
}
class Class2 extends Class1 {
    private $private2;
    protected $protected2;
    public $public2;
}
print_r(new Class2);
```

displays

```
Class2 Object
(
    [private2:Class2:private] => 
    [protected2:protected] => 
    [public2] => 
    [private1:Class1:private] => 
    [protected1:protected] => 
    [public1] => 
)
```

Private properties aren't mentioned in the manual because they're not part of the public interface, they're just for internal use by the class. That's why they're declared private.

Protected properties are documented because you can access them if you define subclasses of `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

`string:Exception:private`.
`string` means a property of `Exception` class that has `private` visibility. Same with the `previous` and `trace`. These three properties are exclusively available only in the `Exception` class. As you noticed, `protected` properties have no class between because it can be passed on the child classes. This statement is also true to `public` properties.